# Json in android project

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, gson, android-api-34

I am using android studio version 2023.3.1. I have a project working with Webservice via Json. I use AsyncTask class but it is old compared to API 34. I want to know how to solve this problem (gson,...)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1T24.png)
Hope everyone can help me come up with a solution

Comment: hello! everyone

Comment: you have error's in build gradle and watch some tutorial before coding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.